# How to use url-loader import multiple images in webpack?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webpack, urlloader

My webpack config:

```
{ test: /\.(png|jpg)$/, loader: 'url?limit=8192' }
```

In my project, I must import images like this:

```
import homeBg1 from './image/homeBg1.jpg';
import homeBg2 from './image/homeBg2.jpg';
import homeBg3 from './image/homeBg3.jpg';
```

The operating is cumbersome, who can give me some advice?Thx!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This code will import all *.jpg files from `image` folder:

```
var requireContext = require.context("./image", true, /^\.\/.*\.jpg$/);
requireContext.keys().map(requireContext);
```

More about `require.context`: https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#requirecontext

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much.