# Webpack file-loader not exporting images

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-2, webpack-file-loader

I am using webpack for my PHP and React project. I want to load a background image from my .scss file with the webpack file-loader but for some reason I don't know, the `img`-folder does not get copied/exported to my `dist`-folder. Below is the webpack.config.js:

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
var path = require("path");
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var WatchLiveReloadPlugin = require('webpack-watch-livereload-plugin');

var DIST_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "dist");
var SRC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "src");

var extractPlugin = new ExtractTextPlugin({
   filename: 'main.css'
});

module.exports = {
   entry: ['babel-polyfill', SRC_DIR + "/app/index.js"],
   output: {
      path: DIST_DIR + "/app",
      filename: "bundle.js",
      publicPath: "/dist"
   },
   watch: true,
   module: {

       rules: [
          {
            test: /\.js$/,
            include: SRC_DIR,
            loader: "babel-loader",
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            query: {
                presets: ["react", "es2015", "stage-2"], plugins: ["transform-decorators-legacy", "transform-class-properties"]
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: extractPlugin.extract({
                fallback: "style-loader",
                use:  ["css-loader", "sass-loader", "resolve-url-loader"]
              })                
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use:  ["css-loader", "sass-loader", "resolve-url-loader"]
        },
        {
            test: /\.(jpg|png)$/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        name: '[name].[ext]',
                        outputPath: 'img/',
                        publicPath: 'img/'
                    }
                }
            ]
        }                      
      ]        
},
plugins: [
    extractPlugin,
    new WatchLiveReloadPlugin({
        port: 'localhost',
        files: [
            './dist/app/*.css',
            './dist/**/*.js',
            './src/app/**/*.png',
            './src/app/**/*.jpg',
            './src/app/**/.*.scss',
            './src/**/*.php',
            './src//*.js'
        ]
    })    
  ]
};
```

I also tried `loader: 'file-loader?name=/dist/img/[name].[ext]',` but with no luck.

My file structure is like this:

```
-- dist
   -- app
        bundle.js
        main.css
-- src
   -- app
     -- css
        main.scss
     -- img
        someimage.jpg
```

Then in my `.scss` i tried this:

```
background-image: url('/img/someimage.jpg');
```

Does anyone have an idea what's wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Try to import the image file in one of your script files like

```
import '/path/to/img.jpg';
```

this will let Webpack know about the dependency and copy it.

Comment: OK this works so far but what if there are multiple images in that folder? I dont want to import each single image file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37313954/how-to-url-loader-multiple-images-in-webpack have not tried it, but it looks promising.

Comment: Oh man seriously? Why is webpack making things so complicated?!? Anyways, thanks for the suggestion :-)

Answer (score 1):

The CSS/Sass loaders do not translate URLs that start with a `/`, therefore your `file-loader` won't be applied here.

The solution is to use relative paths for the imports if you want them to be processed by webpack. Note that CSS and Sass have no special syntax for relative imports, so the following are equivalent:

```
url('img/someimage.jpg')
url('./img/someimage.jpg')
```

If you want them to be resolved just like a module, webpack offers the possibility to start the import path with a `~`, as shown in [`sass-loader` - imports](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader#imports).

Comment: When I do `url('./img/someimage.jpg')` I get `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './img/someimage.jpg'` :-/

Comment: The path must be correct, like with any other JavaScript import. I didn't see that your CSS was in another directory. So it should be: `url('../img/someimage.jpg')`.